# Global structs across DLL?

Tags: c++, dll, global

I'm working on a DLL. This is my `IGlobal.h`, which I include it many time from others `.h/.cpp`:

```
#ifndef _IGLOBALS_
#define _IGLOBALS_

struct IGlobalBitmaps {
    IBitmap mKnobGeneral;
    IBitmap mButtonScore;
    IBitmap mButtonRandom;
    IBitmap mButtonLoad;
    IBitmap mButtonClear;
    IBitmap mButtonShape;
    IBitmap mSwitchGeneral;
};

IGlobalBitmaps gGlobalBitmaps;

#endif // !_IGLOBALS_
```

when I compile the DLL, it says ***LNK1169  one or more multiply defined symbols found***.

What can I do? I can't use `const` (since some `IBitmap` methods are not const) and neither `static` (since its a DLL, and it become a pain later).

Comment: The [/FORCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xttf5w7w.aspx) or/FORCE:MULTIPLE option overrides this error.

Comment: It shouldn't be instantiated from your header. Even then, if you want to use a variable stored in a DLL, you're going to want to declare it: `__declspec (dllexport)` so that it has an exported symbol name.

Answer (score 2):

you should declare the variable as extern in your .h file, and define it in any one of the cpp files.

Answer (score 0):

When declaring a variable in a DLL that you want to use from outside the DLL, you need to give it import/export status.

```
#ifdef BUILDING_DLL
// When building the DLL, export
# define DECL_DLL __declspec (dllexport)

#else

// When building something that uses the DLL, import
# define DECL_DLL __declspec (dllimport)
#endif

DECL_DLL IGlobalBitmaps gGlobalBitmaps;
```

For bonus points, if you load the DLL with `LoadLibrary (...)`, rather than linking to its import library, you can get DLL exported functions and variables by using `GetProcAddress (...)`.

Comment: I don't need to use "outside" DLL :O I just need to use it within the DLL, accessing from every class/instances.

Comment: @paizza: Well, you said you couldn't declare it `static` because it's a DLL. That kind of indicates otherwise.

Comment: Yes, it's a DLL. I'll avoid static because I know using static in a DLL is pain. That's why...

Comment: But you don't seem to know why declaring something `static` in a DLL is a "pain." Even if you stripped off the `static` linkage, you would not be able to use the variables outside the DLL. `extern` linkage is no better. That's what dllimport and dllexport are for.

Comment: Nevertheless, you don't declare global variables `static` in a header and expect that to do something meaningful. Each module that includes your header will see a different version of those variables; that's not global.